# javascript length function throwing an error on text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is accurately reporting the length of the text field in the console.log but it is also throwing the error beneath the code on each keyup. Any thoughts?

```
$('.search').keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = this.value;
            console.log(this.value.length);
            if (this.value.length>0){
            getSuggestions(searchTerm);
            }else{
                $('#Button').click();
            }
        })
```

And this is what I get in Chrome's console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined pm_functions.js:283
(anonymous function) pm_functions.js:283
p.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:2
g.handle.h
```

Comment: What is the HTML for the element(s) with class "search"? Can you tell (in the Chrome script debugger view) for sure that that's the line of code causing the problem?  If the `console.log()` worked, it seems pretty weird that the subsequent line would throw an exception.

Comment: You probably mean `$(this)` not `this`

Comment: Try $(this).val() and/or $(this).text() instead of this.value

Comment: It's working for me. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TQRZw/

Comment: what kind of element is '.search'? is it a `input` or `div` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it is solved. Thanks for the help. I noticed that the `keyup` was firing twice. And the error was being thrown the second time. When I looked closer at the HTML I saw that the parent was also using the ".search" class.

So here's my fix using a strong ID for the input field

```
$('#searchInputField').keyup(function () {
            var searchTerm = this.value;
            if (searchTerm.length > 2){
            getSuggestions(searchTerm);
            }else{
                $('#Button').click();
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

try to replace `this.value.length` with `$(this).val().length`

Comment: Why? That results in trying to access the `length` property of `undefined` as well - the statements are absolutely equivalent (for the most input types)

Answer (score 1):

It is a blind answer, since you have to shared your html

```
$('.search').keyup(function () {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    if (searchTerm && searchTerm.length>0){
        getSuggestions(searchTerm);
    }else{
        $('#Button').click();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could test the value of this.value:

```
$('.search').keyup(function () {
var searchTerm = this.value;
        console.log(this.value.length);
        if ( (this.value.length>0) && (searchTerm !== null) ){
            getSuggestions(searchTerm);
        }
        else {
            $('#Button').click();
        }
    })
```